# Get domain from api call using php?

Tags: php, api, dns

I have scripts from external domains that access our api script on our server, which returns information via json. My question is, if someone made the request from their site to our site for the api script can I get the url/domain the request came from? If so how would I do that? I tried using $_SERVER to get the domain name but that just gives me the domain the api script we host is on.

Im using PHP 4.x, yes will be upgrading soon but not now.

Comment: Would this work for subdomains too? Or just the top level domain? So if someone accessed the api from subsite.mainsite.com will it just get mainsite.com? I guess it depends on the ip address.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your best bet is to check `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']`

Comment: Then i don't think you have much of a chance of knowing what domain it originated from, they are probably using the API serverside and not sending a referer.

You could implement an API key system to track who uses your API.

Comment: how about checking the ip and doing gethostbyadd()

Comment: @G molvi: Interesting idea but i don't think you could get the domain using the API that way. That function returns the hostname for the IP address - That probably wouldn't help him much in this instance.

Comment: @Mick Hansen It actually already uses an api key. I didnt explain everything in my original post. Basically I want to run certain functions based on the site that is accessing the api. But I dont want to create an api for every single domain/subdomain so was trying to do it dynamically.

Comment: i think you need this feature supported by your api then

Comment: @John: Only real way to get the domain on a request is to use HTTP_REFERER, this can of course be spoofed as Kenrick points out.You could  inform your users and tell them that adding an REFERER is required and then matching that to your API. I don't know how other API's handle it, never seen any do domain matching, only the Google API, but that's requested via javascript so easier to check.

Comment: @Mick Hansen Yeah its a weird setup. Its just based on who is making the call I have to do additional steps to determine the data being passed back. The problem is the scripts requesting it can be around 30k different domains and sub domains combined. So I dont want to have to create 30k different api keys, to db intensive and hard to keep track of for what its suppose to do.

Comment: @John Well, the only way i see you being able to add more control is sending a message to your API users that you are changing your procedures and that they need to add valid domains/ips via a control panel on your site - and then maybe give them a 30 day grace period.

I don't see you being able to achieve what you want the setup being what it is now.

Comment: @Mick Hansen Yeah looks like I will have to come up with a better solution, I will try a work around for now until then. Thanks for the help! I will give credit to this answer since its the closest to what Im trying to achieve.

Comment: @John Your welcome, you can contact me via. email (should be in my profile) if you need to discuss this further.

Answer (score 0):

Just note that referrer can be spoofed, so if you are using it for authentication, don't. After you grab the `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']` you can then use this function to parse out the necessary stuffs: [parse_url](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php)